# Alternative title for Easy Breadcrumb

Tags: breadcrumbs, 9

I'm using Drupal 9 and recently discovered [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb). I'd like to use a custom field to overwrite the page title to be displayed in the breadcrumbs, but it seems to be not working.

In the configuration, there is a field "Alternative title field name for breadcrumb" with "field_breadcrumb_title" by default, but when I add a field with this name to my page, it does not display. Instead, I get the page title or (when I disable "Use the real page title") the formated URL segment.

There is a [discription of every configuration field in the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/easy-breadcrumb/configuration-options-for-easy-breadcrumb), but of all things this one is missing.

Does anyone know, if this functionality is working?

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the code, this functionality looks for the `->value` of that field, so it has to be a plaintext field or similar, it cannot be a taxonomy term or formatted text field.

Comment: @Hudri I used plaintext as well as formated and unformated fields. Unfortunately, no result. Checked the code as well, looks promising to me, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This could certainly be a bug in the new future. For those who come across this in the future, the follow up is on Drupal.org:

https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb/issues/2931141